# Symfony 4 - creating a new project (it does not work)

Tags: php, symfony

today I wanted to learn something about symfony and start with basic project setup but it seems like it doesnt work. Here's my steps:

1. I have created new project by writing:
   `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project '4.4.*'` 
   it went well.
2. I started local server with:
   `symfony start:server`
   server started without any problems.
3. My routing looks like this:

   `index:
   path: /
   controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index`

   myController:

   `public function index() {
       return new Response('IT WORKS!');
   }`

But instead of my response im getting

> unable to fetch the response from the backend: malformed MIME header
>   line: [info] Matched route "index".

Why is this happening? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi Faker! How about using Symfony  Annotations to configure the routes?

Comment: the problem persisted unfortunately with annotations

Comment: Did you import  `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this issue is not happening if you create project based on symfony 4.3.*. as I did. I have no idea why it didn't work on 4.4.* thou.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I think it is a recent bug of Symfony https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/274.

My temporary solution is to remove PHP CGI, so Symfony CLI is force to use PHP CLI.

When you run `symfony local:php:list`, if you saw PHP CGI in the table:

```
┌─────────┬────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │ Directory  │ PHP CLI │ PHP FPM │   PHP CGI   │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.4.6   │ /usr/local │ bin/php │         │ bin/php-cgi │ PHP CGI │ *       │
└─────────┴────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Try to remove it by running `apt remove php-cgi`, or if you are in a Docker image, add this line instead `RUN rm /usr/local/bin/php-cgi`:

```
┌─────────┬────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │ Directory  │ PHP CLI │ PHP FPM │ PHP CGI │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.4.6   │ /usr/local │ bin/php │         │         │ PHP CLI │ *       │
└─────────┴────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```